# NVMe Samsung 960 evo (with adapter) + MBA mid 2013

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, ssd

Hello I recently upgraded my MBA with new ssd Samsung 960 Evo 250 GB. I am using adapter ("M key M.2 PCIe AHCI SSD Adapter as SSD for MACBOOK Air 2013 2014 2015 A1465 A1466 Pro A1398 A1502" from Ali). Everything worked fine - installation and running system for few days.

But now I have problems that it keeps itself turned off and now when I started MBA, I get error - folder with question mark and MBA keeps restarting.

Is there any way how to fix this, or I need different SSD?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you **know** that the hardware you specified is indeed compatible with your make/model of MacBook I would first look into everything being installed properly. Make sure everything is seated correctly and there is nothing that does not belong.

You may also want to take the replacement/adapter out and inspect the area around where it is installed for foreign matter (dirt) use some canned air to clean out the system and parts. Inspect for damage (use a magnifying glass!).

Reinstall everything carefully and see if it is any better.

If the same symptoms persist you are faced with possibly replacing (under warranty, hopefully) the SSD and/or the adapter. Contact the reseller and see what they say. They may just take both back. I would be inclined to do just that as there is no way of telling which part is defective.

Answer (score 1):

Start by replacing your old drive into it (you still have it?)... that gives you an immediate A/B split, so you can know if the issue is the change you made or something else.

Some of those adaptors are better than others.. I've seen some which are too thick and cause pressure on the logic board. if that's your case, you could've cracked the logic board with a poorly designed adaptor.

your adaptor could also suffer from junk in the solder joints - which I've seen on some as well.  (we actually inspect every adaptor under a microscope prior to install, to make sure we don't have any short-outs caused by bad chineese quality issues)...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I can post a fix to the same problem.  When I did this upgrade, initially with a SinTech adapter, everything worked fine on re-install, then several days later the system became unstable, wouldn't boot consistently, etc.  The problem turned out to be some of the SinTech adapter pins contacting with the metal on the "shield" of the SSD connector on the logic board.  I insulated the pins (just to the rear of the SSD connection itself) with Kapton tape, and voila!  Problem solved.  I guess over time the adapter moved just slightly (100ths of a mm) as the laptop rattled around in my backpack and caused the short.  At any rate, easy and cheap fix.